# When and why to use &?, =?, @? in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I followed some tutorials to create angular directives. In the isolate scope, some tutorials define scope like this:

```
scope: {
  model: '=?',
  data:  '@?' 
}
```

Meanwhile, some tutorials define scope without question mark like this:

```
scope: {
  model: '=',
  data:  '@'
}
```

Can anybody explain me the difference or the purpose of these with examples? Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `&`, `@`, and `=` symbols are used to define the bindings (one-way, bi-directional, etc) for isolated scope objects, as you already know. [Here is a pretty thorough tutorial on how all this works](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/).

The `?` symbol is used to indicate that the parent scope property to which the isolated scope binding refers to is **optional**. This means that if for some reason the parent scope property doesn't exist, then your application will continue to run without throwing the NON_ASSIGNABLE_MODEL_EXPRESSION exception.

Comment: I understand the difference between &, @ and =, and it makes sense for your explanation about optional. Can you provide an example that isolated scope have optional property and explain why is option?

Comment: Sure, [here is a plunkr showing the functionality without the optional flag.](http://plnkr.co/edit/RI1dZLNBnj3Xc72JYLVj?p=preview) To see how it behaves with the optional flag, add it and you can see it simply returns a 404 instead of throwing an exception.